# is there a possible way to merge excel rows for duplicete cells in a column with python?

Tags: python, excel

I am still new with python could you pleas help me with this
[i have this excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jlSS.png)
[and i want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aneyN.png)

Comment: Here is a thread that you can refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271413/pandas-merge-nearly-duplicate-rows-based-on-column-value

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the csv data to a panda dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("Input.csv")
```

Then do the data manipulation as such:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name'])['Training'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Finally, create an output csv file:

```
df.to_csv('Output.csv', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for creating a `DataFrame` to manipulate the excel sheet information. First, load the file using the function [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel) (this creates a `DataFrame`), and then use the function [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to concatenate the strings.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel File
df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx')

# Group by the column(s) that you need.
# Finally, use the apply function to arrange the data
df.groupby(['Name'])['Training'].apply(','.join).reset_index( )
```