# List to a Readable Representation using Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-representation

I have data as

```
[{'name': 'A', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'B', 'subsets': ['B_1', 'B_A'], 'cluster': 2},
 {'name': 'C', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'D', 'subsets': ['D_1', 'D_2', 'D_3', 'D_4'], 'cluster': 1}]
```

I need to represent it as

```
Cluster Number    Subset                         Name
0                 ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B']          A, C
1                 ['D_1', 'D_2', 'D_3', 'D_4']   D
2                 ['B_1', 'B_A']                 B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I think it is fair to mention that you can actually create a dataframe without `json_normalize`  in your case and apply `groupby` as originally shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271413/pandas-merge-nearly-duplicate-rows-based-on-column-value):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'name': 'A', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'B', 'subsets': ['B_1', 'B_A'], 'cluster': 2},
 {'name': 'C', 'subsets': ['X_1', 'X_A', 'X_B'], 'cluster': 0},
 {'name': 'D', 'subsets': ['D_1', 'D_2', 'D_3', 'D_4'], 'cluster': 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby('cluster')
                       .agg({'subsets':'first','name':', '.join})
                       .reset_index()
                       .set_index('cluster')
                       .rename_axis('Cluster Number')
```

```
                             subsets  name
Cluster Number                            
0                    [X_1, X_A, X_B]  A, C
1               [D_1, D_2, D_3, D_4]     D
2                         [B_1, B_A]     B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_normalize` + `groupby` "cluster" and apply `join` to "name" and `first` to "subsets":

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data).groupby('cluster').agg({'subsets':'first','name':', '.join}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   cluster               subsets  name
0        0       [X_1, X_A, X_B]  A, C
1        1  [D_1, D_2, D_3, D_4]     D
2        2            [B_1, B_A]     B
```

Comment: Kindly check the edited question.